# Error when trying to use Kendo UI with AngularJS and Webpack

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, webpack

I know this question has been asked before, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a realy simple project setup where I want to use Kendo UI with AngularJS and bundle it with Webpack.

Here's the code:

app.js

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'angular';
import 'kendo-ui-core';

var app = angular.module('app', ['kendo.directives']);
```

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app">
        <input kendo-date-picker />

        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./app.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            'window.jQuery': "jquery"
        })
    ]
};
```

But when I run the application, I get following error message:

```
The Kendo UI directives require jQuery to be available before AngularJS. 
Please include jquery before angular in the document.
```

I'm not sure what the problem here is.. Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assertion that produces this error is (from Kendo UI):

```
if (!(element instanceof jQuery)) {
    throw new Error("The Kendo UI directives require...");
}
```

If you put a breakpoint on that line and compare `element.constructor` against `jQuery` they will be different instances, so probably webpack is loading `jQuery` more than once (maybe looking into different folders).

To solve this you can add the [`resolve` option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) to your webpack configuration passing it the path to your `node_modules` folder so that it will only search for modules there:

```
resolve: {
    modules: [__dirname + '/node_modules']
},
```

Comment: Samir: thanks for the insight that Kendo is using a different copy of jQuery!

Answer (score 2):

The present version of kendo-ui-core (2017.3.1116) is configured with a dependency on jquery less than 3.0.0. If your project is using a version of jquery higher than this npm will give kendo-ui-core its own private version of jquery in its own node_module sub-folder. The default webpack configuration will cause any references to jquery within kendo-ui-core to resolve to this private version.

Samir's solution effectively changes the places that Webpack will search for dependencies to exclude any private node_module folders. This may well be fine for your situation, but you should bear in mind that other modules might need their own private versions of some of their dependencies.

An alternative solution is to use an alias for jquery to force every module that depends on it to use the same copy. You do that like this:

```
 resolve: {
    alias: {
        jquery: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/jquery"), 
    },
    modules: ["node_modules"]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like loading order issue. You need jQuery to be available before angular.

Try loading jquery first with a script tag instead bundling it with your src code into bundle.js. Something like

```
<script src="jquery.js></script>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: That works indeed, but this doesn't answer my question.. In app.js I want to import all my dependencies in app.js, not put them in a seperate script tag